How can I accelerate this R code & for loops?
Here is the R code I have right now:
#### Defining a function that returns the daily return of a stock. Return 1 if the return does not exist.
  daily_return <- function(date, ticker) {
    result <- 1 + as.numeric(stock_prices$Return[stock_prices$Date == date & stock_prices$Ticker == ticker])
    if (!length(result)) return(1)
    else if (length(result) > 1) return(na.omit(result)[1])
    else return(result)
  }
  
  for (day in 2:length(table$Date)) {
    date <- table[day, 1]
    return_vector <- as.data.frame(NULL)
    for (ticker in portfolio) return_vector <- c(return_vector, daily_return(date, ticker))
    return_vector <- daily_return(date, portfolio)
    #print(day)
    table[day, 2:length(table)] <- table[day-1, 2:length(table)] * return_vector
  }

The parent function takes a portfolio of ticker symbols, looks up the daily return of each ticker symbol in a data frame called "stock_prices", and creates a "table" of the amounts invested in each position, one row per day.
This is what the data frame "table" looks like:
> returns(1, ymd("2000-01-15"), ymd("2000-02-15"), 1000000)
        Date        C       BAC      WFC      CMB      ONE      FTU      FBF      MER      KRB      JPM     FITB
1 2000-01-18 245283.7 101903.70 79394.42 72822.12 44836.78 42684.20 36291.70 36277.75 27294.77 26551.28 25002.62
2 2000-01-19 245283.7 101903.70 79394.42 72822.12 44836.78 42684.20 36291.70 36277.75 27294.77 26551.28 25002.62
3 2000-01-20 236417.9  98220.39 76524.71 70189.96 43216.15 41141.38 34979.94 34966.49 26308.20 25591.58 24098.90
4 2000-01-21 236417.9  98220.39 76524.71 70189.96 43216.15 41141.38 34979.94 34966.49 26308.20 25591.58 24098.90
5 2000-01-24 230806.8  95889.23 74708.47 68524.07 42190.46 40164.93 34149.72 34136.60 25683.80 24984.19 23526.94
6 2000-01-25 230806.8  95889.23 74708.47 68524.07 42190.46 40164.93 34149.72 34136.60 25683.80 24984.19 23526.94
       STI      USB      MEL       TD       WM      NCC      PNC      BFO       WB       RY      WMI     BBT
1 24570.15 20773.41 20422.58 19190.63 17588.92 16964.09 16823.68 16736.54 16692.47 15856.15 12906.71 12043.2
2 24570.15 20773.41 20422.58 19190.63 17588.92 16964.09 16823.68 16736.54 16692.47 15856.15 12906.71 12043.2
3 23682.06 20022.56 19684.41 18496.99 16953.16 16350.92 16215.59 16131.60 16089.12 15283.03 12440.20 11607.9
4 23682.06 20022.56 19684.41 18496.99 16953.16 16350.92 16215.59 16131.60 16089.12 15283.03 12440.20 11607.9
5 23119.99 19547.34 19217.22 18057.98 16550.80 15962.85 15830.73 15748.73 15707.26 14920.30 12144.94 11332.4
6 23119.99 19547.34 19217.22 18057.98 16550.80 15962.85 15830.73 15748.73 15707.26 14920.30 12144.94 11332.4
       BCM      KEY       BMO      ASO      CMA
1 11946.88 11750.87 10626.291 8389.442 8374.949
2 11946.88 11750.87 10626.291 8389.442 8374.949
3 11515.06 11326.13 10242.203 8086.206 8072.237
4 11515.06 11326.13 10242.203 8086.206 8072.237
5 11241.76 11057.32  9999.115 7894.288 7880.650
6 11241.76 11057.32  9999.115 7894.288 7880.650

This is what the data from "stock_prices" looks like (this data frame has 3,000,000+ rows:
> head(stock_prices)
        Date Ticker   Price    Return Share_Count Market_Cap
1 1986-01-17   CAYB 13.7500         0         494   6792.500
2 1986-01-20   CAYB 14.2500  0.036364         494   7039.500
3 1986-01-21   CAYB 13.8750 -0.026316         494   6854.250
4 1986-01-22   CAYB 13.3125 -0.040541         494   6576.375
5 1986-01-23   CAYB 13.1875 -0.009390         494   6514.625
6 1986-01-24   CAYB 13.0000 -0.014218         494   6422.000

The "portfolio" object is literally just a list of ticker symbols.
The issue is that this code is very slow. The data frame "stock_prices" has millions of rows. And I know that for loops are slow in R, but I haven't figured out myself how to vectorize this chunk of code. Can you help me refactor this code to make it run faster?
Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you!
I have tried (without avail) to vectorize the daily_return function.

Welcome on StackOverflow, Stephen Nemo! Please do add samples of table and stock_prices. You can do so by pasting the output of dput (example: dput(head(table))).

Pivot your stock_prices data frame into long format. group_by stock and use lag (possibly with ifelse) and avoid the for loops altogether.

Can you add samples of portfolio?

Rather than building a data.frame, vectorize collecting daily_return and convert to a dataframe or list after that collection.

Something like library(tidyverse); table |> pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "Ticker", values_to = "Amt_Invested") |> left_join(stock_prices)

Maybe add a small reproducible example with expected output so that others can verify possible solutions. Use dput() to provide a small sample of the data as mentioned.
